# Different session between domain and subdomain

Tags: php, apache, oscommerce

I've deployed Oscommerce portal over domain.com and sub.domain.com, but I see when I login from domain.com, I was also loggedin from sub.domain.com itself because session is shared.

I want to separate the sessions of domain.com and sub.domain.com, both website should not be linked, one solution is that I change all the session variables of both side, but I want any easy solution in which I don't need to modify source code.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: how you set cookie? can you post that part of the code?

Comment: this sounds like something you should be posting on their community forums

Comment: @Akam     ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', '0');
    ini_set('session.cookie_path', 'domain.com'); //and sub.domain.com
    ini_set('session.cookie_domain', 'domain.com'); //and sub.domain.com

Comment: @UnholyRanger its a normal PHP and apache question, it doesn't matter if u use oscommerce or something else

Comment: @UnholyRanger no, I'm using domain.com and sub.domain.com, both are different in code

Comment: please update your question with these information and also provide how you set cookie with PHP

Answer (score 0):

I assume OsCommerce has Cookie settings in admin page.
Make each site has unique Cookie name.

sample.com => sample_coookie
sub.sample.com = > sub_cookie

etc...